# WebView not working correctly on orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a Universal app with a webView which resize when an orientation change occurs.
On the iPad simulator, the webView automatically reflows to fit the new width.
But on the iPhone simulator, the content doesn't reflow and some of it gets cut off.

Is this a known WebView Bug ? How do I fix this issue?

My webview just loads a remote html page.

I am testing on IOS 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interface builder, you have to adjust the properties of the WebView to make it stretch on orientation change. Make sure you did that. It looks like this in Xcode:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

IT is very simple you implement this code

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
 {

    CGRect frame = webview.frame;//UIWebView* webview;
    frame = self.view.frame;
    webview.frame=frame;
    NSString *embeded_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head> <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 000\"/></head><body style=\"margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param></object></div></body></html>",frame.size.width,frame.size.height ,video_url];//url for video
    [ webview loadHTMLString:embeded_url baseURL:nil];//reload the web view from cache 

}
```

didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method is called at the time of orientation change occurred    and resize your web view. My webview just loads a remote html page and it works fine in 4.X & 5.X