# Orientation IOS WebView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a app that contains a WebView.
Now when app is open, the default is Portrait.
But I should like to change the orientation when the phone change to landscape.
I don't know how.
In this moment the app don't change the orientation.
Ever in Portrait.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebView not working correctly on orientation change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549960/webview-not-working-correctly-on-orientation-change)

Comment: I add a code to when the phone change from Portrait to Landscape, the view change with the orientation, but the size of the view don't resize so well.